# Okta Support for IDP initiated auth flows

Tags: reactjs, authorization, okta

Is it possible to gain access to information of the currently active Okta session when launching an application from the Okta dashboard in order to attempt to login the user immediately to the Okta account without needing to go through the SSO login redirect flow?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about OIDC app. You can configure them to allow auth flow to start from Okta, by setting "Login initiated by" to "Either Okta or App". That will give you an option to specify an app URL where id_token will be sent after a user click on a chiclet.